# Can't access OMDb API

Tags: javascript, api, axios

I'm currently trying to implement a search suggestion function by calling the OMDb API using an axios GET request, but I keep getting an undefined error.

The GET request seems to work fine if I use another API and also if I enter the address onto my browser, but returns an error every time I try to access this particular API using axios.

Would greatly appreciate any help I can get with this...thank you for your time!

Here is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/adrianchan94/pen/Vwmxwae?editors=1011) link.

```
window.onload = function () {

var search = document.getElementById("searchbox");
search.addEventListener("input", add);
  
async function add() {
console.log(search.value)

let url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=353ee81e"

await axios.get(url)
  .then( response => {
    console.log(response.data)
    return response.data;
  })
  .catch( error => {
    console.log(error)
    return error
  });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two solution :

```
const url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=353ee81e"
axios.get(url).then(response => {
    console.log(reponse.data)
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

or

```
const url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=353ee81e"
try {
   const r = await axios.get(url)
   const response = r.data
   console.log(response)
} catch (error) {
   console.log(error)
}
```

You can't await with then because await get the value from the promise.

Comment: Thanks for your response @mehdim2, I tried these suggestions just now but unfortunately neither of those solutions seemed to fix the error